# EF 6 - Ninject - The operation cannot be completed because the dbcontext has been disposed

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ninject, dispose, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I've seen a lot of questions with this error, so sorry for asking again, but no solutions have worked for me so far.

I'm working on a ASP.NET Web API project that's using the Ninject and Ninject.Web.Common references, where a DbContext is injected into the repositories. This error pops up the second time I send a request subsequently.

My stack trace :

```
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CheckContextNotDisposed()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ObjectContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.DetectChanges(Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetStateEntries(Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetStateEntries()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbChangeTracker.Entries()
   at Project.Data.UnitOfWork.Commit() in c:\Projects\Project\src\DotNet\Project.Data\UnitOfWork.cs:line 22
   at Project.Api.Infrastructure.UnitOfWorkAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext) in c:\Projects\Project\src\DotNet\Project.Api\Infrastructure\UnitOfWorkAttribute.cs:line 25
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
```

Ninject : RegisterServices

```
kernel.Bind<DataContextFactory>().ToSelf().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("nameOrConnectionString", "Project");
kernel.Bind<DataContext>().ToMethod(context => kernel.Get<DataContextFactory>().GetContext()).InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<IRepository<Device>>().To<Repository<Device>>();
kernel.Bind<IRepository<Person>>().To<Repository<Person>>();

kernel.Bind<UnitOfWork>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();

kernel.BindHttpFilter<UnitOfWorkAttribute>(FilterScope.Controller).WhenControllerType<DeviceController>();
kernel.BindHttpFilter<UnitOfWorkAttribute>(FilterScope.Controller).WhenControllerType<PersonController>();
```

My IRepositiry class

```
public interface IRepository<TAggregateRoot> where TAggregateRoot : class, IAggregateRoot
    {
        void Save(TAggregateRoot instance);

        void Remove(TAggregateRoot instance);

        TAggregateRoot One(Expression<Func<TAggregateRoot, bool>> predicate = null, params Expression<Func<TAggregateRoot, object>>[] includes);

        IQueryable<TAggregateRoot> All(Expression<Func<TAggregateRoot, bool>> predicate = null, params Expression<Func<TAggregateRoot, object>>[] includes);

        bool Exists(Expression<Func<TAggregateRoot, bool>> predicate = null);

        int Count(Expression<Func<TAggregateRoot, bool>> predicate = null);
    }
```

My person controller class

```
public class PersonController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IRepository<Person> _personRepository;

    public PersonController(IRepository<Person> personRepository)
    {
        _personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    ...        
}
```

My DbContext

private readonly IDictionary _configurations;

```
public DataContext(string nameOrConnectionString, IDictionary<MethodInfo, object> configurations)
    : base(nameOrConnectionString)
{
    _configurations = configurations;
}

public virtual void MarkAsModified<TEntity>(TEntity instance) where TEntity : class
{
    Entry(instance).State = EntityState.Modified;
}

public virtual IDbSet<TEntity> CreateSet<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
{
    return Set<TEntity>();
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    if (modelBuilder == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("modelBuilder");
    }

    foreach (var config in _configurations)
    {
        config.Key.Invoke(modelBuilder.Configurations, new[] { config.Value });
    }

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: What does your UnitOfWork class look like?